# Is the Continuum Hypothesis equivalent to: $\forall S(S\subseteq \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N})\implies |S|\leq|\mathbb{N}|\vee|S|=|\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N})|)$?

Tags: set-theory

We know that the Continuum Hypothesis $\text{CH}$ asserts that
$$\not\exists S\big(|\mathbb{N}|<|S|<|\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N})|\big).$$
So certainly (*where $\mathbb{P}$ is the powerset*) we know
$$\text{CH}\implies\forall S\big(S\subseteq \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N})\implies |S|\leq|\mathbb{N}|\vee|S|=|\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N})|\big),$$
as well as the contrapositive
$$\neg\Big[\forall S\big(S\subseteq \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N})\implies |S|\leq|\mathbb{N}|\vee|S|=|\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N})|\big)\Big]\implies\neg\text{CH}.$$
But is this biconditional? That is to say, if there *doesn't* happen to exist a subset $S\subseteq\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N})$ (specifically of the natural numbers) whose cardinality is between $|\mathbb{N}|$ and $|\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N})|$, does that imply $\text{CH}$ is true?

This is really my first deep dive into infinite cardinality, so I'm having trouble wrapping my head around if the specific set, ($\mathbb{N}$, in this case) makes a difference. My initial thought is that if this statement is true, then it should apply for any substituted set with cardinality equivalent to $|\mathbb{N}|$, thus the statement would be equivalent to $\text{CH}$. Then again, if the statement were true for the natural numbers, how can I be sure that there isn't some other more abstract set whose cardinality is equivalent to $|\mathbb{N}|$, but has a subset which breaks $\text{CH}$?

Comment: If there is a set $S$ such that $|A|\lt|S|\lt|B|$ then there is a set $S'\subseteq B$ such that $|A|\lt|S'|\lt|B|$. In fact, $|S|\le|B|$ ***means*** that there is a set $S'\subseteq B$ such that $|S'|=|S|$.

Comment: @bof this makes sense, I appreciate the intuitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Continuum Hypothesis asserts that for the successor cardinal $\aleph_1$ of $\aleph_0$ it holds that $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}=|\mathbb{P}(X)|$, where $|X|=\aleph_0$.

The cardinal numbers are well ordered (under ZFC), so every cardinal number has a successor and, by definition, there is no intermediate cardinal number between $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$. Thus, if $Y$ is a set with $|Y|=\aleph_1$ and $Z$ is an infinite subset of $Y$, then either $|Z|=\aleph_0$ or $Z=\aleph_1$.

If CH holds, then saying $|Y|=\aleph_1$ or $|Y|=2^{\aleph_0}$ is the same thing.

Comment: This is true in ZFC, but in ZF the statement $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ is in fact stronger than the statement "There is no intermediate cardinal".

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's why I added “under ZFC”. Removing choice opens up several problems about well-ordering of the cardinals, as far as I know.

Comment: More to the point here, problems about the well-ordering of the continuum. My point is that this is why, in some sense, the correct statement for CH is the one in the question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see, but then the OP should provide more context. I doubt that for a first dive into infinite cardinals choice is avoided.

Comment: The thing is that choice is irrelevant at all for the question at hand. So saying that CH is something else, and circumventing the question is kind of a bad answer (not in the sense that it's misleading or that it's incorrect, just in the sense that it's somewhat unsatisfying).